# JQuery" bind to attribute changing

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, binding

I have some `fieldset` element, which sometimes may have `active` **class** (not *pseudo*-class) in declaration. 
Any way to bind events to css or attribute changing on HTML elements?

Comment: _Any way to bind to class changing on HTML elements?_....what type of question is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a jquery plugin, called watch.js. 
https://github.com/darcyclarke/Watch.js